# properly call a function in parent class without getting in recursive loop

Tags: python

In this python code, The last command caused a recursive loop but when I enter just "queue" on the prompt it did not cause a loop. What is the difference between the 2 usages and how can I correct it? Can you offer some help ?

```
class Queue(list):

    # Add element to this queue
    def enqueue(self,e):
        self.append(e)

     # Return a string representation of this queue
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self)


queue = Queue() # Create a queue
queue.enqueue("Tom ") # Add it to the queue
print("print queue ", queue)
```

Comment: Thanks to Ignacio, I was able to fix the error with these commands: return super(Queue,self).__str__()  or return self.__repr__()  or
        return super(Queue,self).__str__()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typing in a variable name in the REPL prints the representation of the object as returned by its `__repr__()` method.

Since you derive from `list`, either use `super()` to get a proxy for the next class in the MRO, or dispatch to `list.__str__()` directly.

Comment: Yep.  Though it might seem obvious, it might be worth pointing out that OP's recursive loop happens because `str(self)` simply calls `self.__str__()` which calls `str(self)` which calls ... and that is _why_ you need to avoid calling `str(self)` and instead need to delegate to `list.__str__` somehow.

Comment: Or, let the default `__str__` take care of it?

Comment: @thefourtheye agreed. The `__str__` method as defined here doesn't seem to be doing anything except causing the OP's problem.